# Report in Cognos 10 in 2 formats

Tags: cognos

how can i make a report in Cognos 10 using render variable so that i can achive results on same page. Report should have a dropdown choice for user to view output in LIST or CROSTAB.

Answer (score 1):

- There are a few ways i'll show one that you are already very close to getting.

  1. Create a Variable named something like "vReportFormat" that say does a case on the parameter that determins the format

Example

Variable Name:  vReportFormat

Case 
     When ?Param? = 'List'
     Then 'List' 
     Else 'Crosstab'
   End

1. In the Render Variable Property of the List select your newly created variable "vReportFormat" and then select only the output value "List"  that you created when you made the variable.  By selecting only List when the report runs it will evaulate the variable first and then the list will only render if the output value is 'List'  - Repeat this variable assignment for the crosstab but of course pick 'Crosstab' as the output value.
2. There are other variations like creating two report pages and using the render variable on the Page object itself - works the same exact way.

Hope this helps.